# Default Date year set at 1970

Tags: java

I need to parse a String that does not originally have the year set like 
"13 Aug 11:30"

but when I output the date it adds the year on,
I tried set year but the year is totally wrong the output comes as "Thu Aug 13 11:30:00 GMT 3911"

Is there a way to set the year after the date is parsed?

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm");

String dateStr = "13 Aug 11:30";
Date fromDate = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr);


fromDate.setYear(2011);
```

Comment: the title is not describing the question it seems?

Comment: Why not add the year to the string before you parse it?

Comment: @Martin Because I'm parsing the Date from a html tag and it does not have a year

Comment: Do you _want_ to output the year, and assume current year? Because, if you're not interested in printing the year you can let it be any "incorrect" default it happens to be and just fix your output format to exclude it.

Comment: The `setYear()` and many other methods of `java.util.Date` is not without reason *deprecated*. Don't use deprecated methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Calendar` to set the year:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(fromDate);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
fromDate = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the API for the [`setYear`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setYear%28int%29) method?

> Sets the year of this Date object to be the specified value plus 1900

2011 + 1900 = 3911

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `java.util.Date` states quite clearly that `setYear()` adds 1900 to the year passed in. Just subtract 1900 from your argument.

Comment: Beware of leap years: 1900 wasn't a leap year but 2000 was. I agree with your comment about adding the year to the string; that seems the simplest to me.