# Year goes to 1970 when comparing the TimeStamp

Tags: java, android

I need to compare if the current time is between `X+30` and `X-30`.

Everything going fine with timestamps but when comparing year is set to 1970; So output is not accurate.

```
String string1 = "04:41 PM";
        Calendar calendar1,calendar2,calendar3,calendar4 ;
        DateFormat time1;
        Date time;
        try {
            time1 =new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            time = time1.parse(string1);
            calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar1.setTime(time);
            System.out.println(time1.format(calendar1.getTime()));
            calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar2.setTime(time);
            calendar2.add(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
            System.out.println(time1.format(calendar2.getTime()));
            calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar3.setTime(time);
            calendar3.add(Calendar.MINUTE,-30);
            System.out.println(time1.format(calendar3.getTime()));

            calendar4=Calendar.getInstance();

            System.out.println(time1.format(calendar4.getTime()));
            Date now = calendar4.getTime();
            if (now.after(calendar3.getTime()) && now.before(calendar2.getTime())) {
                //checkes whether the current time is between 14:49:00 and 20:11:13.
                System.out.println(true);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `hh:mm a` format `YEAR` field is [set to 1970 by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996045/default-date-year-set-at-1970).

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing points in time,
>   defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap
>   seconds.

So in your case you want to ignore `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY_OF_MONTH` fields when comparing the dates so do this  (this resets the `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY_OF_MONTH` fields):

```
calendar4.setTime(time1.parse(time1.format(calendar4.getTime())));
```

after:

```
calendar4=Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: its working after ignore month and date also...thanks bro